# Dragging file at the Dock creates a copy of a file?

Tags: macos, finder, dock

When I drag and drop a file from Finder to Dock, it creates a copy of the file somewhere? I would like to create some type of link as I know from Windows. Until now I created a link (`context menu -> Create a link`) and used a this link instead of using original file. What procedure is correct?

[image: You can see that two of these three icons are a links and one is original file.]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dragging a file/folder into the Dock just creates a reference there, it does *not* duplicate the file/folder. In your case you can omit the "create a link" step.

The reference to said *object* is stored in the `$HOME/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dock.plist` file under the **persistent-others** key as a **Dictionary** labeled **Item N** where **N** is the next available number starting from **0**.  Among the information stored about the *object* is its pathname so the *object* can be opened when its Dock Tile is clicked.

```
    <key>persistent-others</key>
    <array>
            <dict>
                    <key>GUID</key>
                    <integer>86167247</integer>
                    <key>tile-data</key>
                    <dict>
                            <key>arrangement</key>
                            <integer>2</integer>
                            <key>displayas</key>
                            <integer>1</integer>
                            <key>file-data</key>
                            <dict>
                                    <key>_CFURLAliasData</key>
                                    <data>
                                    AAAAAACkAAMAAQAA0HpGVwAASCsAAAAAABuw
                                    VwAxxNoAANB6bMcAAAAACSD//gAAAAAAAAAA
                                    /////wABAAgAG7BXABsCdgAOABQACQBEAG8A
                                    dwBuAGwAbwBhAGQAcwAPABoADABNAGEAYwBp
                                    AG4AdABvAHMAaAAgAEgARAASABNVc2Vycy9w
                                    c2UvRG93bmxvYWRzAAATAAEvAAAVAAIACv//
                                    AAA=
                                    </data>
                                    <key>_CFURLString</key>
                                    <string>file:///Users/pse/Downloads/</string>
                                    <key>_CFURLStringType</key>
                                    <integer>15</integer>
                            </dict>
                            <key>file-label</key>
                            <string>Downloads</string>
                            <key>file-mod-date</key>
                            <integer>3497684167</integer>
                            <key>file-type</key>
                            <integer>2</integer>
                            <key>parent-mod-date</key>
                            <integer>3497684167</integer>
                            <key>preferreditemsize</key>
                            <integer>-1</integer>
                            <key>showas</key>
                            <integer>1</integer>
                    </dict>
                    <key>tile-type</key>
                    <string>directory-tile</string>
            </dict>
    </array>
```

Comment: To add to what patrix said, the reference to said _object_ is stored in the `$HOME/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dock.plist` file under the **persistent-others** key as a **Dictionary** labeled **Item N** where **N** is the next available number starting from **0**.  Among the information stored about the _object_ is its pathname so the _object_ can be opened when its Dock Tile is clicked.

Comment: @user3439894 edit the answer and add that in it improves the answer greatly